# iOS 9 Dialog Box and form elements

Tags: ios, ux-designer

I have a task at work to change a workflow of a cancellation form. I've been asked to change an iOS dialog box to include 2 select menus that users would use to select how many people they are cancelling for and select from 4 cancellation reasons.

Not only does this sound like a bad UX idea, but I don't think I've seen select menus in iOS dialog boxes. Am I correct about that? I've seen text fields, but never select menus that would prompt the scroll select that's shown in the bottom of the attached screenshot.[image: Select menu screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely correct and doing it will make the dialog look really weird on iOS.

Now that your problem is more complex, you have to move on to another interface. Drop the dialog and use a modal window, it will be even better than the dialog because you will be able to show the questions and their answers on the same screen.

I drew an example to you based on what you shared about the problem.

[image]

If you don't want to use the numeric stepper, you can instead write on the cell "Choose amount of people" and when user taps in it, you open the numeric picker of iOS.

PS: I was a bit confused because you asked about iOS but the images you shared are all from the web, hope my idea helps you since it is better suited for the native environment. Also, the text is not perfect as I don't know more about the context of the cancellation.